# Create hyperlink button cells in gridview using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am having a GridView in my web page. Which is displaying the data with the columns as **Status, Name , Id and Action**. My status column always filled with the 3 values(**Complete, Queued** and **Failed**) randomly.

Now I want to display this status column values as a link ,If it is having the value either "Failed" or "Queued". But "Complete" status should not be display as a link.

How Can I achive this design during the runtime?

My Code for binding the data into the grid is,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtActionList = clsactionList.GetADActionList();
        grdADActionList.DataSource = dtActionList;
        grdADActionList.DataBind();
    }
    protected void grdADActionList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grdADActionList.Rows)
        {
            if ((gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text == "Completed")
            {
                (gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Visible = true;
                (gvr.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink).Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

using this code I am just simply binding the values in the grid. I am not able to create the Status column as having link buttons based on the binded values for that status column.

My .aspx Code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdADActionList" runat="server" Height="83px" Width="935px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdADActionList_RowDataBound">

     <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='http://localhost:52807/Default.aspx?'><%# Eval("Status") %>
                 </asp:HyperLink>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="GivenName" HeaderText="GivenName"/>
```

Please help me to do this further....

Comment: How does the markup for `grdActionList` look like?

Comment: @Andrei: Do u mean the design of the grid?

Comment: Yes. The content of aspx file related to the Grid

Comment: Its simply a Grid, have taken from the tools and binded with the Datatable values in that.... How can I create the template column based on the cell values as a link

Comment: For now all your columns are auto generated. This is fine if you are ok with default gird appearance, however when you need customization you should switch to manual columns declaration

Comment: @Suryakavitha Andrei means, you have to do `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` and specify all the columns you want programatically.

Comment: @P5Coder: I have changed the design code as per Anderi words.

Comment: Try `if((gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text.ToLower() == "complete")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GridViewDataBound event, just hide the link and display a simple label if the value is **complete**.
**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='your_url'>
            <%# Eval("Status") %>
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Status") %>" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void onGridViewDataBound()
{
    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in grd)
        if((gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text.ToLower() == "complete") // Updated Line
        {
            (gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Visible = true;
            (gvr.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink).Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code, Its creating hyperlinks for the entire column and Completed status also displaying as link

Comment: Do you have `OnDataBound="onGridViewDataBound"` in your `asp:GridView` tag? Else it won't fire the C# `onGridViewDataBound()` event handler which hides the link if status = "completed".

Comment: Yes, I have that in my code. I'll edit my post and will update my latest code... The problem is , OnDataRowBound event it does not enter into the condition   if((gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text == "Complete")

Comment: Please see I have updated the C# code where it says "updated Line". Use that line and it will work.

Comment: The problem is, gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text  does not return the cell value. When I am using the following attribute inside the label control Text="<%# Eval("Status") %>" , I'm getting some formation error. So I changed it like    Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"

Comment: I have changed the label design code with single quote for the Text attribute as Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' . Now Its working. Thanks a lot. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to work in design file means .aspx file
you have to use  and

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hyperlink">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CODE", @"http://localhost/Test.aspx?code={0}") %>' 
        Text='link to code'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place an handler on RowDataBound event

```
protected void gw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)    
    {

        DataRowView v_DataRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        string NavigateUrl = <....place your link here with DataRowView info>

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", NavigateUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you have your columns auto generated, so first disable that feature. Then you need to define each column as a BoundField, and for the hypelink, taking into account your condition, the best way is to define template field:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdADActionList" runat="server" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" 
               Height="83px" Width="935px"
               AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/link/address" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'
                                   Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Status") != 1 %>'/>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'
                               Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Status") == 1 %>'>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note that this is just a variation - you have not specified what values does `Status` column contain, so I assumed this is int-based enumeration.

Comment: Please note she has clearly stated **My status column always filled with the 3 values(Complete, Queued and Failed) randomly.**

Comment: @P5Coder, well, I understand it as the column can contain one of three values, depending on which hyper link is either shown or not. Is this incorrect?

Comment: She has auto-generated the columns means she clearly hasnt specified any `url`s to those links. But i think the hyperlink again will depend on the value.

Comment: I am having one doubt in this. Are Hyperlink and Link button same? I need link buttons on that particular cells not as hyperlink.

Comment: Not at all. Link button can have `OnClick` event handlers. And they look different. You can use whatever control you like in the `TemplateField`.

Comment: @Suryakavitha, `Hyperlink` and `LinkButton` are a bit different and behave differently. Basically `HyperLink` is a simple link, while `LinkButton` behaves like a button although on the page it appears as a link as well. For eaxmple, click ob hyperlink will cause a redirect, while click on link button causes a postback of the current page. You should use the one suiting your needs